# How do I recode excel data into new rows?

Tags: r, excel, spss

I want to recode a set of GDP data, but I can't find a command that gets it into a format that I could merge into my other data sets.

The data currently looks like

| Country Name | 1960 | 1961 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aruba | 5,000,000 | 5,400,000 |

And so on for each year, but I need it to look like

| Country name | Year | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aruba | 1960 | 5,000,000 |
| Aruba | 1961 | 5,400,000 |

I've been screwing with the data with r, excel, and SPSS, and I don't know how to do this in any of them. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -Country_Name)`

Comment: Okay, I did that, now I just have one minor hiccup. It put an x in front of the year names when I imported the data for some reason. Instead of saying 1996 it says X1996 and so on.

Comment: The obvious fix would recoding the import to not add the X. If you cannot do that R "coerces" types silently. Thus, with X+number you created now a character variable (or strings). You can manipulate characters/strings with multiple approaches. Here a simple "replace with empty" like `gsub(x = "Year", pattern = "X", replacement = "") will help.

Comment: In SPSS you can use the `varstocases` command. Like this: `varstocases /make year from var1 to varn /index=ivar(year).`